# How to get inline style values and send to Django

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, django

I created Django application using draggable images with jQuery, it's working well, however I need to save, the new top and left positions in Django Model.
I was trying a way to send inline style informations for some input type="hidden" value = "??? style"

Look, after user move picture Jquery Draggable send this :

```
<div id="draggable-1" class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="position: relative; left: 3px; top: 1453px;  "> 
    <img src="static/img/image.png" width="80" height="200">
</div>
```

Javascript to this resource in only:

```
<script>
    $( "#draggable-{{forloop.counter}}" ).draggable();
</script>
```

I need these numbers from left and top informations to send to a Django view and save database model.

any suggestion, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#events) library allows you to pass a configuration object to. There are callback functions that you can provide which will hook into different events. I'd suggest using the `stop` hook in order to send an http request of the updated position like so:

```html
  <body>
    <div
      id="draggable"
      style="cursor: pointer;"
    >
      <p>Drag me</p>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
      $("#draggable").draggable({
        stop: function () {
            const { top, left } = this.style;
            console.log(`top ${top} | left ${left}`);
            fetch("/your-django-endpoint-here", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ top, left }),
            });
        },
      });
    </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: Thank you probaly it is the way, I put my django template and receive some message issue drag:51 POST http://192.168.15.101:8888/movimenta 403 (Forbidden) it could be token?